# Alert not displayed immediately when .show() method executed

Tags: java, android, android-alertdialog

I am building and displaying an AlertDialog, but the alert is not appearing when the alert.show() method is called (in line 15 of the code below). It is appearing much later in the logic - after the end of the code sample below.
This code is from an Activity class (extending ActionBarActivity), and is executed when a button on the associated layout is clicked.

Why is my alert not being displayed immediately after the alert.show() method is executed on line 16?

```
public void onClickChooseFolder(final View v) {
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    builder.setTitle("Confirm");
    builder.setMessage("Is your folder on an external SD card?");
    builder.setPositiveButton("YES", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            // Do something here
        }
    });
    builder.setNegativeButton("NO", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            // Do something here
        }
    });
    AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
    alert.show();
    int permission = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,
            Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE);
    if (permission != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        Log.i(TAG, "Permission to read external storage denied");
    }
    permission = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,
            Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE);
    if (permission != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        Log.i(TAG, "Permission to write external storage denied");
    }
    String m_chosenDir = "";
    Boolean m_newFolderEnabled = false;
    // Make the folder list ListView visible
    DirectoryChooserDialog directoryChooserDialog =
            new DirectoryChooserDialog(SourceFolders.this,
                    new DirectoryChooserDialog.ChosenDirectoryListener()
                    {
                        @Override
                        public void onChosenDir(String chosenDir)
                        {
                            String sourceFolder = chosenDir;
                            //Check whether the chosen folder is empty or invalid
                            File f = new File(sourceFolder);
                            File file[] = f.listFiles();
                            //If file is null then the source folder isn't valid
                            if (file == null) {
                                Toast.makeText(SourceFolders.this, "Selected folder is not valid",
                                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                                return;
                            }
                            int fileCount = file.length;
                            if (fileCount < 1) {
                                Toast.makeText(SourceFolders.this, "Selected folder is empty",
                                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                            }
                            // Add the folder to the folder list
                            // If this is not the paid version of the app then clear the folder list before adding this to it
                            // (Only one folder allowed in free version)
                            if (Utilities.upLoadFiles(SourceFolders.this) < 10) {
                                folderlist.clear();
                            }
                            //save the folder list to source_folder preference
                            folderlist.add(sourceFolder);
                            SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(SourceFolders.this);
                            SharedPreferences.Editor edit = prefs.edit();
                            Set<String> set = new HashSet<String>();
                            set.addAll(folderlist);
                            edit.putStringSet("source_folders", set);
                            edit.commit();
                            refreshListViewFromPrefs();
                            setListViewOnClickListener();
                            String fileName;
                            int imageCount = 0;
                            int videoCount = 0;
                            for (int i = 0; i < file.length; i++) {
                                fileName = file[i].getName();
                                if (fileName.endsWith("jpg") || fileName.endsWith("JPG")|| fileName.endsWith("jpeg")|| fileName.endsWith("JPEG")) {
                                    imageCount++;
                                }
                                if (fileName.endsWith("mp4") || fileName.endsWith("MP4")|| fileName.endsWith("avi")|| fileName.endsWith("AVI")) {
                                    videoCount++;
                                }
                            }
                            if (imageCount>0 || videoCount>0) {
                                Toast.makeText(SourceFolders.this, "Selected folder contains " + imageCount + " photo(s) and " + videoCount + " video(s)",
                                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                                return;
                            } else {
                                Toast.makeText(SourceFolders.this, "Selected folder contains no photos or videos",
                                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                                return;
                            }
                        }
                    });
    directoryChooserDialog.setNewFolderEnabled(m_newFolderEnabled);
    directoryChooserDialog.chooseDirectory(m_chosenDir);
    m_newFolderEnabled = ! m_newFolderEnabled;
}
```

Comment: How do you know its displayed after line x?

Comment: I'm debugging it on a connected phone. I first see the alert dialog created by DirectoryChooserDialog, then when that closes I see the alert dialog from line 15 of the code. And I've stepped through the code line by line to check that line 15 gets executed first